# Send keys on div / non input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm testing a site (in Chrome) that has a "spotlight search" feature like on Macs, where an input shows up when you press a certain key. There is a directive that takes care of the logic for this, and you can type anywhere in the application, as long as it's not an input. I need to test this feature by sending keys through my protractor tests, but I get `unknown error: cannot focus element` when I target a div. Is it possible to send keys on an element that isn't an input?

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991003/cannot-focus-web-element-to-send-keys

Comment: I am already using `browser.ignoreSynchronization` and `browser.sleep(5000)` as that answer suggests, still have the same problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would probably need to *wait for the element to become visible* with a [`visibilityOf` Expected Condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf) and [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(by.css("div#myid")), 5000);

var div = element(by.css("div#myid"));
div.sendKeys("test");
```

Also, you can try utilizing [`browser.actions()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions):

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(div).sendKeys('test').perform();
```

Also, you may need to click the element before sending keys:

```
div.click().sendKeys("test");
```

Comment: `browser.actions().mouseMove(div).sendKeys('test').perform();` was the one that worked for me. Thanks!